# ASP.NET Web API 404 File or Directory not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5

I'm having a very strange error. I have a web api app running on IIS 7.5. It works fine local and for the most part on the server. The issue is, I have a file I need to access from the server side. I tried putting the file in the app_data folder, at the root of the site and even at the root of the c drive.

On local everything works fine, but on the server, nothing works at all. Even when I hard code the path to the file. I keep getting 404 errors. So to be clear, I need to access a file "c:\filepath\hello.txt", for example. I can't seem to find that file on the server at all.

None of these work.

```
string pathToFile = "C:\\filepath\\";
string pathToFile = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~\\");
string pathToFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
string pathToFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
```

I know there are a lot of topics for this. The following did not work for me:

Specs:
Visual Studio 2013
ASP.NET WEb API
IIS 7.5

Any ideas?